# How to disable this log "Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1"

Tags: android

I use AudioRecord to record voice in Android App. 
And I have this log when I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy S.

```
02-21 15:56:11.676: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.691: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.716: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.726: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.736: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.751: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.776: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.791: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.806: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.817: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.826: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.836: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.847: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.857: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.866: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.876: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.887: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
02-21 15:56:11.897: V/AudioRecord(22301): Overrun user: 140, server: 280, flowControlFlag 1
```

This is my code

```
// Get the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object. 
        int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize( RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                              RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                              RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING
                                                             ); 
        // Initialize Audio Recorder.
        AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                                     RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                     RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                     RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                                                     bufferSizeInBytes
                                                    );
        // Start Recording.
        audioRecorder.startRecording();
        int numberOfReadBytes   = 0; 
        byte audioBuffer[]      = new  byte[bufferSizeInBytes];

        // While data come from microphone. 
        while( true )
        {
            numberOfReadBytes = audioRecorder.read( audioBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes );  
        }
```

I try to disable this log but I don't know how. 
Please help me. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Samsung left these logs in the `AudioRecorder`, which I'm assuming that they did then you **CANNOT** remove them as these are logs in the internal android frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.@JoxTraex. Is these logs make my app slower?

Comment: With a 1GHz snapdragon processor in your Samsung Galaxy S tablet, its almost insignificant, however; don't try controlling something you have no access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply do not want to see this logs during the development, you can create a simple filter that will silent these type of tag.

Comment: Ok. thanks for your help. I have just do this :D I'm afraid of speed becouse it print many logs per secord.

Comment: Mark your question as solved - then it will be not in the list of unanswered questions.